# Build up a list, but mind the previous elements

Tags: list, prolog

I've stuck with the following problem:

I want to build up a list one-by-one from head to tail. But I have a condition, which depends on the already inserted elements.

```
condition(Sofar, Element) :-     
    between(1, 150, Element2),  
    \+member(Element2, Sofar),
    Element = Element2.

makelist(L) :- maplist(condition(L), L).
```

An important note:  `Sofar` must not contain `NewElement`, what I just try to assert! This is the point, where all my tries failed, because, with maplist, there is a reference in the list which gets the value of `NewElement`

Of course I have more complicated conditions like this, but if I could solve this, then I could adapt it.

Comment: Could you explain more clearly what you want to achieve? What is the purpose of `condition`, for example? If you want to add an element to a list depending upon a condition, then at the very least you need the original `L` and then a new list variable to hold the updated list, `NewL`, or something like that.

Comment: Are you looking for [convlist/3](http://www.swi-prolog.org/pldoc/doc_for?object=convlist/3)?

Answer (score 4):

You are trying to map notions you have learned in command-oriented (a.k.a imperative) languages to Prolog. Names like `Sofar` or `makelist` imply that you are doing something step-by-step. Try to see all of this from another angle by describing how the list looks like:

> A list of elements between 1 and 150 that are all different.

```
all_dif([]).
all_dif([E|Es]) :-
   maplist(dif(E), Es),
   all_dif(Es).

speciallist(Es) :-
   all_dif(Es),
   maplist(between(1,150), Es).
```

Or, using [clpfd](/questions/tagged/clpfd):

```
:- use_module(library(clpfd)).

specialfdlist(Es) :-
   Es ins 1..150,
   all_different(Es).
```